# Vue2 component somehow modifying prop

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

So I've got a vue component I'm using as an editing interface...
The database has a jsonified array inside of it (don't ask... I don't like it either), which has to be in a particular format... In order to allow admins to edit this string array without breaking the format, I'm making a vue editing component which will break the parts up into various textboxes etc...

I would like to have two separate variables - one for what the string array IS, and one for what they are changing... the first variable would be updated when they saved their changes...

The issue I have is that for some reason, when I update one of the variables... not only does the other variable change... but the prop changes as well...
I was under the impression that components could not change their props..?

In particular, the array looks something like this:

```
[
    '1',
    '2'
    ['1','2','3','4']
]
```

And when I do a `.splice()` on the sub-array, both variables and the prop updates...

Some sample code...

Laravel blade view:
`<editor :somearray={{ $someJsonifiedArray }}></editor>`

Component props/data setup:

```
props: {
    somearray: {
        default: [],
        type: Array
    }
}

data(){
    return {
        editedArray: this.somearray,   // This is what will be saved
        wipArray: this.somearray       // This is what changes as they edit
    }
}
```

Some of the methods:

```
resetChanges(){
    this.wipArray = this.editedArray;
}
```

I'm probably missing something obvious... or misunderstanding how things work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javascript Array/Object is passed by reference, not by value!](https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c)

if you do this

```
return {
    editedArray: this.somearray,   // This is what will be saved
    wipArray: this.somearray       // This is what changes as they edit
}
```

whenever you edit `editedArray` or `wipArray`, you are actually editing `somearray`, because they all refer back to the same array/Object .

So you gotta clone the array/Object  instead of passing it directly. The simplest way to clone object is by using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (or in some cases, [deep cloning](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep) will be required). The simplest way to clone array is by using [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

```
return {
    editedArray: {...this.somearray},   // This is what will be saved
    wipArray: {...this.somearray}       // This is what changes as they edit
}
```

Comment: ah ha. I actually remember reading that arrays are passed by reference somewhere last month >.> ... I'm facepalming so hard right now...

I added .slice()... and so far it seems to be working... If I hit any issues, I'll reply, otherwise I'll chuck this as accepted after my tests. Thanks heaps for the quick informative reply